# How to keep previous SSH connections alive while SSH ports get blocked by iptables?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, iptables

I'm trying to build a SSH system that lets me in using SSH (port 22). Then If I block the port using iptables:

`sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 22 -j DROP`

It would keep the previous connection(s) alive.

Is it possible?

System: Ubuntu 20

Comment: What Linux flavor are you using and which one? What is the goal here?

Comment: Linux system Ubuntu. I'll update the question as well :)

Comment: i suggest you need an allow established connections rule prior/before the drop rule like `sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

Comment: @Pax then you most probably want to work with `firewalld`. Having that said, have a look at `iptables-apply` command. It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to block attempts to make new TCP connections on port 22 while existing connections remain unaffected, try using

```
# iptables -A INPUT -j DROP -p tcp --syn --destination-port 22
```